# Asking for how to do a Leave-p-out cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I am currently working on the comparison of models in pollution mapping. I have already finished the model, but I would like to cross-validate my model in terms of leave 30% and 10% out cross validation. I understand the usage of LOOCV from caret but that is no clue for the leave-p-out cross validation in R. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is K-fold cross-validation. It's defined in terms of the number of times you train and evaluate the model (k) instead of the amount of data you leave for validation, but they are functionally equivalent. 10-fold cross-validation is equivalent to your *leave-10%-out* cross-validation.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33474200/2228339) answer describes an implementation using caret.